# How can I change the swap partition in Loki

Tags: release-loki, swap

I tried running `sudo nano /etc/fstab/` but such a file did not exist. So `nano` displays the following error:

`[ Error reading lock file /etc/.fstab.swp: Not enough data read ]`

Some other background info about my setup, I had a swap parition defined during the OS installation but due to space constaints on my main partition I deleted it, and consumed the space.

Afterwards I added a second drive to my system and I'm trying to use one of its partitions as the swap. This is possible with `GParted` using the `swapon` command but it needs to be done after every reboot.

Is there a way to permanently set the new partition as my swap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As lemonslice said, you need to edit `/etc/fstab` and not `/etc/fstab/`.
You can use GParted to find your UUID (right click > informations).

---

Then just add a ligne to fstab like this `UUID=YOUR_UUID none            swap    sw              0       0`. I made you a screenshot to show you my configuration :

[image: http://nsa38.casimages.com/img/2016/12/12/161212052324528993.png]

Comment: Thanks, I shall report back in an hour or two. (My workspace is cluttered atm). Is there a command to quickly check the current swap in elementary?

Comment: You can use `cat /proc/swaps` or `swapon -s` to find devices used for swap and `cat /proc/meminfo` or `free` show you memory use.

Answer (score 4):

You can check the UUID of your (new) swap space:

```
user@host:~$ lsblk -f -o NAME,FSTYPE,UUID | grep swap
├─sda3 swap   ce70123c-6341-4802-9b96-29c39fb4110b
```

You should edit `sudo nano /etc/fstab` (without the trailing slash) and add the line (make sure you use your UUID):

```
UUID=ce70123c-6341-4802-9b96-29c39fb4110b none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: The trailing slash seems to make no difference, I'm getting the same error on nano.

Comment: Edit: I ignored the error and saved the file (as new), I shall report back if it worked.

Comment: If there is a fstab in another place, you can find it with `whereis fstab`

Comment: for your system to work you should have `fstab` in `/etc/`, this file cannot be in another directory

Comment: @lemonslice you're right it was there, wonder why nano was acting up... Anyways issue is sorted, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command to get the UUID of your swap partition:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
```

Edit your `/etc/fstab` and change the uuid

```
# swap was on /dev/sdax during installation
UUID=put_the uuid_here none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Assign the new uuid ( change `sdax` with yours)

```
swapoff /dev/sdax
mkswap -U put_the_uuid_here /dev/sdax
swapon -a
```